# Laravel - Attaching "user_id" to "hangout_id"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship, pivot-table

I'd like to create a website where "hangouts" are displayed and users are able to click on "join" and attend the event.

I want to make it so that when a user clicks on join, their user_id gets attached to the relevant hangout_id in the hangout_user pivot table. By doing so, their name should be appended to the bottom of the attendee list.

I tried to use a form submit to attach the user_id but I'm pretty sure I did it incorrectly.

**How can I correctly create this join button?**

Screenshot of website
[image: Screenshot of Website]

**Code for join button and displaying attendees**

```
{!! Form::model($hangout['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['HangoutController@update', $hangout->id]]) !!}

<div class="form-group panel-footer" style="text-align:center">
    {!! Form::submit('Join', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'style'=>"width:45%"]) !!}
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:33%;padding-left:3%">Attendees</th>
            <th style="width:33%">First Name</th>
            <th style="width:33%">Surname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($hangout->users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-left:5%">{{1}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->firstname}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->surname}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you very much for your time :)

**Edited to add further details**

The result I'm after is for the pivot table hangout_user to have rows of hangout_id and user_id. Using the picture below as an example, this would mean user 1 will be attending hangout 1 and hangout 2.

[image: hangout_user pivot table]

Comment: can you explain which kind of result you want in database

Comment: Hi Yagnik - I've edited the post to include additional information. Hope this helps

Comment: why don't you used the ajax for the join event make upadate related table of related hangout_id add user_id and put new html of success of ajax and remove the join button who already join the event.

Comment: Unfortunately because I don't know how to :( I'm quite new to programming so still learning as I'm going through various tutorials... can you guide me in the right direction please?

Answer (score -1):

You can have an `attendees` column in your hangouts table. Then store attendees like so:

[0,2,5,7,18,21,4]

Each number represents the ID of a username.

So basically when a user "joins" a hangout, you grab the whole hangout's attendees value, decode it, push the ID of the user to the array, and update the value again (after encoding, of course).

If you are unsure how to perform an action after submitting a form, it's done like so:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'HangoutsController@someAction')) !!}
```

Comment: Hi Ariel - thanks for helping. Would this be easier than using a pivot table and attaching the user_id? Something along the lines of...

$hangout->users()->attach(Auth::user()->id) ?